# How to display Attribute Value in Acumatica report header?

Tags: attributes, report, erp, acumatica

How to display Attribute Value in Acumatica report header?
Requirement is to display Acumatica Business Account information Attribute in the Header information of a Report.  For example, there is an Attribute say "Special Member" and it holds the Value "Yes".  This information should be displayed in the Report Header along with the other BAccount table fields.

```
Format:
Report Header
----------------------
BAccount Name: XYZ Company
Special Member: Yes
----------------------
Report Detail:
-----------------------
Activities List...
```

Can anyone indicate what Join we need to use to achieve this?  In the Acumatica Report designer there is only one place where we can define Relationships.  How to relate this information and that too pull that information on the Header of the Report?

Answer (score 2):

there are these four DACs that deal with attributes viz.

CSAnswers
CSAttribute
CSAttributeDetail
CSAttributeGroup

Linking back to specific entity (in your case BAccount) is based on CSAttributeGroup.Type and CSAttributeGroup.AttributeID joined to CSAnswers.EntityType and CSAnswers.AttributeID where CSAnswers.EntityID = BAccountID

Hope this will help!

thnx